# Firebase Too many arguments. Run firebase help emulators:start for usage instructions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-tools

I´m executing

`firebase emulators:start --only functions, firestore`

and getting

`Error: Too many arguments. Run firebase help emulators:start for usage instructions`

---

[image]

[image]

What could be the problem?

## as Federkun suggested worked

[image]

Could the command interpreter be able to accept the white space or just ignore it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space between `functions, firestore`:

```sh
$ firebase emulators:start --only functions,firestore
```